# Get Laravel redirect object URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If my website domain is `domain.com` and I have a Laravel redirect object:

```
$redirect = redirect()->to('someuri');
```

How to return the full URL of `$redirect` object
(in this example is `http://domain.com/someuri`)?

I don't want to use `url()` function. Just need to get the url of this exact redirect object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please add `getTargetUrl` method like:

```
$URL = redirect()->to('someuri')->getTargetUrl();
```

Comment: @Omid It's component from Symfony. Laravel just extends a bit. Check out `Http-foundation api`

Comment: still they could mention that this is extending some Symfony component. But their documentation shows me this a native Laravel component and I should guest if it can work like symfony component.